# WCF Service Application VS ASP.NET Web Application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, wcf

I'm building a Web API to access my database. I would like to create a Single Page Application Website first then a iPhone, Android and Windows application. Classic.

My data and business layer are already finished.

1. First I decided to build a Json WCF Webservice. In Visual Studio I created a **WCF Service Application**. I modified the Web.config file to accept Json requests and implemented my interface and svc file.
2. After that I discovered **ASP.NET Web Application** with the **Web API template**. So I decided to change and to create a real web API with this full website structure.

Now I'm lost. **What are the differences between these two possibilities to create a Web API?**

Comment: I found an answer here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8198fcb4-396a-4ded-9c45-160106dc8b9f/wcf-service-application-vs-aspnet-web-service-application?forum=asmxandxml

All new web service development should be done using WCF. The "ASP.NET Web Service" templates are still left for legacy purposes.

But the answer is from 2009...

Comment: That link is talking about the asmx web services, not Web API. Web API is better suited for Http Rest services while WCF is a more generic service oriented framework. See [this msdn comparison](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj823172(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A comparative from microsoft : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj823172(v=vs.110).aspx

Personnaly, I prefer WCF because the datacontracts are generated in the case of SOAP Web Services with WSDL files.