# Simplest Visual Studio project to make calls to a web service

Tags: visual-studio, iis, wsdl, visual-studio-2019, iis-10

I was wondering what currently is the lightest VS project to make calls to a web API and that can be hosted on IIS? From what I see available, I can either do an ASP.NET WebApp or WCF Service Application. However I'm not sure which one would be considered overkill for something that will only interact with Active Directory and make a few calls a day.

edit: After reading this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26399868/wcf-service-application-vs-asp-net-web-application) and the provided link to an [official comparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/wcf-and-aspnet-web-api?redirectedfrom=MSDN) I realize it's pertinent to note that half of the calls to to be made will be triggered through a browser.

Answer (score 1):

None would be overkill for that. However, a WCF service application will be much lighter for **your specific use case.**

Comment: I found this link to a [comparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/wcf-and-aspnet-web-api?redirectedfrom=MSDN) between the two from a similar [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26399868/wcf-service-application-vs-asp-net-web-application). It seems the asp.net web api would be better suited for calls from a browser.

Comment: To calls from a browser, but you **didn't** said anything about that in your question. You just asked in a very general way. Also, keep in mind that *suitability* and *performance* are two different things. I also said, **for your specific use case**.